# Sync Evolution with Android apps through Owncloud or other centralised online source

Tags: android, evolution, notes, task-management, owncloud-server

I'm hoping someone can help with this as I'm so close to achieving my perfect workflow environment.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a laptop and an android smartphone. Overall what I'd like to achieve is having my files, contacts, calendars, tasks and notes (memos) synced across both devices and being able to view/edit them through a browser.

I already have an owncloud account with a provider and have managed to successfully sync contacts and calendars with Evolution using the `DAVdroid` android app.

Using the `My Own Notes` android app I'm able to access my notes in owncloud, however I have found no way to access them through Evolution (or any other desktop app I've tried).

I use the `Task Sync` app in android to sync tasks with my android phone and evolution, however the outcome is somewhat buggy, this is more the android app's fault than anything else I think.

Prior to this I was using all google services, however I would like to move away from them if possible.

Basically my questions are:

1. Is there a method I can sync my owncloud notes with evolution and my
   smartphone?
2. Is there a better approach to syncing tasks through
   owncloud?
3. Has anyone successfully synced Evolution with all owncloud
   apps?
4. Is there another centralised sync service besides owncloud
   that I can use which would meet my needs?

Comment: Meanwhile DAVdroid supports syncinc tasks (see: https://davdroid.bitfire.at/configuration). Using the tasks of ownCloud also works with Evolution via CalDAV (same URL pattern as described on the mentioned DAVdroid page, just with `caldav://` as protocol. I've checked the "secure connection" as well, works for me). Using OC's calendar and contacts with Evo; the latter sometimes require a restart of Evo to refresh (when new entries added from the other end), and I get error messages when adding entries in Evo (still seems to work). No other apps tried with Evo yet.